# Renaming files in a loop

Tags: bash, unix

I have a list of files: `File_2011_1.txt`, `File_2011_2.txt`, `File_2011_3.txt` ... `File_2011_100.txt`; I want to update 2011 to 2012 in all the file names.

The following doesn't work:

```
for FILES in `ls`; do NEWNAME=`echo ${FILES} | sed -e 's/*2011*/*2012*/'`; echo ${FILES} ${NEWNAME}; done;
```

but this does:

```
for FILES in `ls`; do NEWNAME=`echo ${FILES} | sed -e 's/File_2011*/File_2012*/'`; echo ${FILES} ${NEWNAME}; done;
```

So, why does a wildcard in before the part of the filename I want to change not work?

Comment: Funnily enough you're using a wildcard when you shouldn't and `ls` when you should see [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) for why `for Files in \`ls\`...` is a bad idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because sed uses not a [File willcard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character) (like it was in bash or DOS), but regex ([regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)).

You can do just `sed -e 's/2011/2012/'` (by default 's' command of sed matches part of string). Wildcard `*` will be written as `.*` in regex language.

Basic rules of sed regexps:

- The caret (`^`) matches the beginning of the line.
- The dollar sign (`$`) matches the end of the line.
- The asterisk (`*`) matches zero or more occurrences of the previous character.
- The dot (`.`) matches any character.
- The `[` and `]` are used to match set of characters, e.g. `[a-c01]` matches with single char any of: `a`, `b`, `c`, `0`, or `1`.